# What is the approach to create a nested list from a linear tree structure in java

Tags: java, tree

My objective is to create a class to represent the hierarchical pattern of category in java. Now from database i get the path i need to construct like below;

"123_456_789"
"123_67"
"895_444"

the above mentioned 2 strings are obtained as input. My objective is to convert the above data in to below structure

```
categories[
    {
    categoryId:123,
        subcategories[{
            categoryId:456,
                subcategories[{
                    categoryId:789
                    }]
            },
            {
                categoryId:67
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    categoryId:895,
        subcategories[{
            categoryId:444
            }]
    }]
```

What is the easiest way to convert the input to a java object like the class with list of categoryIds.

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to store it in a tree type data structure and then print as like how json pretty print does.

You need gson jar in classpath and you may find it at: [gson.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar)

Here is the working code for your asked question:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class MainTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr[] = new String[] { "123_456_789", "123_67", "895_444" };
    Node node = new Node(null, arr);
    // System.out.println(node);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(node.toString());
    String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
    System.out.println(prettyJsonString.replaceAll("\"", ""));
}

static class Node {
    String value;
    List<Node> list;

    public Node(String value, String arr[]) {
        this.value = value;
        list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
            Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
            for (String str : arr) {
                int _ = str.indexOf("_");
                if (_ > 0) {
                    String key = str.substring(0, _);
                    String currentValue = str.substring(_ + 1);
                    List<String> list = map.get(key);
                    if (list == null) {
                        list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    list.add(currentValue);
                    map.put(key, list);
                } else {
                    map.put(str, null);
                }
            }
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                    list.add(new Node(entry.getKey(), null));
                } else {
                    list.add(new Node(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
                            .toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()])));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this.value == null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("{\"categories\":[" + "\n");
            Iterator<Node> iter = list.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(iter.next());
                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
            }
            sb.append("]}");
            return sb.toString();

        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Node> iter = list.iterator();

            sb.append("{\"categoryId\":" + value + "}"
                    + (iter.hasNext() ? "," : "") + "\n");
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                sb.append("{\"subcategories\":[" + "\n");
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    // sb.append("{");
                    sb.append(iter.next());
                    // sb.append("}");
                    if (iter.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }
                sb.append("]}" + "\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
}
```